# Stateful value based on Context property not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component with a stateful value that is based on a prop from Context, and when i update my Context value, the stateful value is not also updated.

```
export default function PomoTimer() {
  const { state } = useContext(AppContext)
  const { pomodoroDuration } = state
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(pomodoroDuration)

  console.log('pomoDuration', pomodoroDuration)
  console.log('timeLeft', timeLeft)
  ...
}
```

Here when I update PomodoroDuration from the Context, the timeLeft stateful value is not equal to the new PomodoroDuration.
I want the "timeLeft" value to be always updated and equal to the new pomodoroDuration when I update it, how can I do it?

When i change my Context.pomoDuration to a new value, this is logged :

```
pomoDuration 30
timeLeft 50
```

However i am initializing my timeLeft stateful value with the pomoDuration value `const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(pomodoroDuration)`, so I don't really understand what is happening here. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State is only ever instantiated once, when the component mounts. If you want to update the `timeLeft` state when the context updates then use an effect with a dependency on `pomodoroDuration` for that. If you are familiar with class-based components then an `useEffect` hook with dependency is equivalent to `componentDidUpdate`.

```
export default function PomoTimer() {
  const { state } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { pomodoroDuration } = state;
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(pomodoroDuration);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeLeft(pomodoroDuration);
  }, [pomodoroDuration]);

  ...
}
```

Side note: Don't console log state updates in the body of functional components, you should also use an effect for that.